# What is the meaning of this と "and" or "with"?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

皆さん、こんにちは！
昨日、新しいコロナウイルスについて読んで、何か面白いものを見つけた！
これで手伝ってくれないの？
 So, I found a bit confusing the following sentence:
この女性の娘と結婚している男性にも、ウイルスがうつっていました。
In the beginning I thought that the meaning of this sentence was "the daughter and husband of the woman" (to whom the sentence makes reference) because as you know と can mean "and" 日本と中国 = Japan and China
                      娘と結婚している男性= daughter and husband
But also と can mean "with" 
So I concluded that the meaning of the sentence is 
"The man who is married to this woman's daughter" 
But I just wanna be sure I'm right with this

Comment: 気をつけましょう... If you weren't aware, 手伝ってくれないの？ sounds basically like 'What, you aren't gonna help me?' If you want to say 手伝ってくれませんか casually, just say 手伝ってくれない？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's safe to say that the only realistic translation is "The man who is married to (with) this woman's daughter" as you said.

Grammatically you could parse it as {この女性の娘}と{結婚している男性} "this woman's daughter and a married man" but who is this married man who suddenly appears out of context? That would be silly.

As for your other translation "the daughter and husband of the woman", you wouldn't use 結婚している男性 to refer to someone's husband, so we can discount this option too.